# jquery: add classname to object

Tags: jquery

I have a button that triggers an off-canvas sidebar. When the off-canvas sidebar is active, then the menu button is not clickable.
Therefor i'm trying to look up for the classnames "js-off-canvas-exit" and "is-visible" then the menu button should get the class name "is-active" otherwise this class name should be removed from menu button.

My attempt looks like this:

```
  var menuButton = document.getElementById('menuButton');
  menuButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    menuButton.classList.toggle('is-active');
    e.preventDefault();
  });


  $('.js-off-canvas-exit .is-visible').click(function() {
    menuButton.removeClass('is-active');// add classname is-active to menuButton
  }


  $('.js-off-canvas-exit:not(.is-visible)').click(function() {
    menuButton.addClass('is-active');// remove classname is-active from menuButton
  }
```

Can someone help me to get this working?

Comment: remove space `'.js-off-canvas-exit .is-visible'` and try with `'.js-off-canvas-exit.is-visible'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `menuButton` is native DOM element, you need to create jQuery object. since  [`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) and [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) methods are available to jQuery object not DOM elements.

```
$(menuButton).removeClass('is-active');
```

instead of

```
menuButton.removeClass('is-active');
```

You can use `add()` and `remove()` of [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) object.